# facebook-unity-sdk 6.1

Tags: unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I am getting this error after importing the facebook sdk on my unity 4.6.1 , anyone can help me with a solution on this?

Assets/Facebook/Scripts/IOSFacebookLoader.cs(6,42): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `FB' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure but I think you are missing the line "using Facebook.MiniJSON" at the top of your code.

Answer (score 0):

An error in another script someplace in an existing project could be preventing compilation of the Facebook .cs files, which would make the FB class inaccessible.

Is this in a new Unity project (for testing) or an existing Unity project? Have you tried following the "[Get Started with Facebook Unity SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/getting-started/canvas)" tutorial to set up the Interactive Console scene in the Facebook console?